# Entity Relationship Model: Ternary Relationships

Tags: entity, entity-relationship, ternary

I am trying to understand why this statement in the book is wrong: "given a C entity, there is at most one related A entity and at most one related B entity". 
Is it that it doesn't apply to a specific kind of relationship?? 
So, if I have an example of a student who is in attendance to a course with a type of subject. The entities are student, attendance, course and subject. Student makes attendance in a room. Also, a student can make attendance for a subject. Does this example apply to the statement?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The author probably means: in a single relationship *instance* (e.g., student-Bob/course-ABC/attendance123). So there is a single student, a single course and a single attendance record linked in that instance.

Not across all relationship instances in the class (where student Bob could attend many classes over time).